# How to get all value from the same name of input text fields in codeigniter4?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4, form-helpers

**View**

```
               <?php 
                      $quant_data = array(
                                          'class'       => 'form-control',
                                          'name'        => 'prodquantity[]',
                                          'id'          => 'prodquantity[]',
                                          'placeholder' => 'Enter Product Price',
                                          'type'        => 'number',
                                          'value'       => 250
                                        );

                      echo(form_input($quant_data));

                      if($validation->getError('prodquantity')){                              
                          echo '<span class="text-danger">'.$validation->getError('prodquantity').'</span>';
                      }
               ?>
               <?php 
                      $quant_data = array(
                                          'class'       => 'form-control',
                                          'name'        => 'prodquantity[]',
                                          'id'          => 'prodquantity[]',
                                          'placeholder' => 'Enter Product Price',
                                          'type'        => 'number',
                                          'value'       => 500
                                        );

                      echo(form_input($quant_data));

                      if($validation->getError('prodquantity')){                              
                          echo '<span class="text-danger">'.$validation->getError('prodquantity').'</span>';
                      }
               ?>
              </div>
```

**Controller**

```
$prodquantity = $this->request->getVar('prodquantity');
```

But getting only 500.

How to get all values it in CI4?

Answer (score 0):

If we declare the name as an array "[]", while getting the value for a particular name we also write "variableName[]",
Please try below code.

```php
$prodquantity = $this->request->getVar('prodquantity[]');
```

Comment: I got the solution.... just need `prodquantity = $this->request->getVar('prodquantity');`.... bracket [] is not needed!

Comment: @MayurKoshti would you please elaborate on what was the issue if the code is the same?